# How do I know this function is return empty..and how do I show it?

Tags: php, javascript

I am not familiar with javascripts...so cant understand how do I check which variable return empty?? if tweet is there then it fill with tweets but if not then it wont show up. but I want know which varible is fills the container and if I want show "there is no tweets for you" then where will I add that??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.twtter.start({
        searchType:"searchWord", 
        searchObject:"google", 
        lang:"en", 
        live:"live-180", 
        placeHolder:"twitterdiv", 
        loadMSG: "Loading messages...", 
        imgName: "loader.gif", 
        total: 6, 
        readMore: "Read it on Twitter", 
        nameUser:"image", 
        openExternalLinks:"newWindow", 

    });
    $("#twitSearch").submit(function(){

        $.twtter.start({

            searchType:"searchWord",

            searchObject:$(".twitSearch").val(),
            live:"live-180", 

        });
                return false;

    });


})
```

the result is displayed in

```
<div id="twitterdiv"></div>
```

THanks

Comment: Please provide some code for us to look at.

Answer (score 1):

No, Javascript is client side PHP is server side. There is a massive conceptual chasm between the two.

[Server Side Vs. Client Side](http://www.virtualshowrooms.co.za/articlepage.php?cp=101)

Comment: ok if so can any one tell me how do I go about this?? say I do have a page wich give twitter search results. so what I want is when results return empty then it should hide the caption saying twitter search results...otherwise it show up even though the result is empty..it give an empty space below that caption and looks odd..

Comment: How are the twitter results retrieved, through Javascript or PHP? If they are retrieved through Javascript then the whole process (checking the results and modifying the page) should be done in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning** Stupid answer ahead

### JavaScript

```
window.location = 'script.php?test=' + myVar;
```

### PHP

```
echo (empty($_GET['test'])) ? 'empty' : 'not empty';
```

This should be ringing warning bells.

You can not use PHP to check if a JavaScript variable is empty, at least not in a way that doesn't make you (or others) say *WTF*.

What you probably want is a different way to do it. You can send all JavaScript variables to a PHP script, and then validate them in the PHP. Post more code please.

Or if you just want to do it inside of JavaScript, you can do it like this (if it is a string)

```
if (myVar === '') {
   alert('empty');
}
```

or if you'd rather have an `empty` function like the PHP language construct, go with

```
function empty(str) {
    return (str === '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can not check whether or not a javascript variable is empty with php*. If you could post your code, we could get to your problem better.